# CSS pseudo element on text disappears after line-break

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I add a ":after" element to all links (simulate a "border-bottom") so on ":hover" i can animate this pseudo element ("height: 100%"). This works fine, but when the link is split with a line-break the pseudo element is broken after the line break.

```
a {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;

&:after {
  transition: height .1s;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: -3px;
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

&:hover:after {
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
}

&:hover {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Here is a pen:

http://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/YWKmQJ

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an inline element, background will be more efficient: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pbzMYP

```
a {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) bottom repeat-x;
  background-size:3px 3px;
  transition:1s;

  &:hover {
    background-size:100% 100%;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is even better than the code I stole from another site, thank you.

Comment: @HenningFischer so these link animation effect  might be interresting for you too ...  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/grRmBw http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yOzrxM

Comment: Not bad, I'll keep this in mind for a futuristic website design ... with lasers ;).

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from another site - it works with animated background gradient :)

```
a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 0%, red 100%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 0 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 150ms ease;

      &:hover {
          color: white;
          background-size: 1em 1.5em;
      }
  }
```

Updated the pen.